# Increment excel formula by 1

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to copy and paste a few cells keeping the format and them ebing linked to a table.

Currently i have a table but i am referencing it from another sheet
e.g:

```
=Sheet2!A1  =Sheet2!B1  =Sheet2!C1
=Sheet2!D1  =Sheet2!E1
```

I'm trying to copy it down 4 lines at a time and paste multiple times, the values keep going to the current cell ID but i'm wanting to increment them by 1 each time, e.g. when i paste i would like them to be:

```
=Sheet2!A2  =Sheet2!B2  =Sheet2!C2
=Sheet2!D2  =Sheet2!E2
```

Is there any quicker way than manually changing all of the cell ids to +1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you want and run the following in VBA:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell  As Range

    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.HasFormula Then myCell.Formula = myCell.Formula & "+1"
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

---

If you press it too many times, this is how to remove it the last `+1`:

```
Public Sub UnTestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.HasFormula Then myCell.Formula = Left(myCell.Formula, _
                                                Len(myCell.Formula) - 2)
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

---

Concerning the comment of @SJR, if you want to change the **reference address** of the cell, this is one possible workaround:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.HasFormula Then myCell.Formula = Left(myCell.Formula, _
                                                Len(myCell.Formula) - 1) & 2
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Simply change the `&2` to the number you want to refer to.

Comment: Won't that turn `=Sheet2!A1` into `=Sheet2!A1+1`?

Comment: @SJR - yup, this is exactly what it returns. But it is not manual.

Comment: Doesn't the OP want `=Sheet2!A2` instead, i.e. 1 added to the row number?

Comment: @SJR - that's an option as well and probably you are right. Edited the answer.

Comment: Hi Again! That worked a treat thank you! I can't seem to figure out how would i be able to update the reference addresses for the following code? if it's possible


        =IF(ISBLANK(IDdata!$A$2),"",IDdata!$A$2)

Comment: @steveybo - try to pass the formula as a string. E.g. `.LocalFormula = "=IF(ISBLANK(IDdata!$A$2),"",IDdata!$A$2)"` Then `.LocalFormula = "=IF(ISBLANK(IDdata!$A$2),"",IDdata!$A$" & something_here & ")"`. It is not very easy, thus give it a try a bit (it will not happen in the first 1 hour), thus try harder.

Answer (score 0):

A math trick.

`=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&INT(ROW()/4)-*offset*)`

Addjust *offset* first and then you can copy and paste it down as you wish.

The `ROW()` returns the row number where the formula located. For example, if the formula you type is in cell `A20`, `ROW()` returns 20. i.e. if you need to show `Sheet2!A1` in `A20`, the offset should be 4. The formula becomes `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"INT(ROW()/4)-4)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your_Sheet_Name").Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Modify the above code.  What this is doing is selecting cell A99999 and then using the Ctrl and up arrow command to select the last row with a value and offsetting by one so it actually selects the cell below that.  You can then paste whatever you want into that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Code I've Written for myself. It's fairly simple to edit with changeable increments and Row spacings.

```vb
Sub MakeFormulas()
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourWorksheet")
    Dim field As String
    Dim formula As String
    Dim i As Integer: i = 2 'Every x Line you want to Paste your Formula to
    Dim a As Integer: a = 7 'Starting Row Number of Data on the Sheet you want to fetch
    Do While i < 1000 'How many Rows down you wan't to paste it to
        field = "C" + CStr(i) 'Column where you paste to + The Row Number
        formula = "=Switches!A" + CStr(a) 'The Reference Column + Row Number which gets incremented.
        sh.Range(field) = formula

        a = a + 1 'By which Number your FOrmula should get incremented
        i = i + 2 'Every i (Second) row gets the Formula Pasted.
    Loop
End Sub
```